# how do I create a multidimensional dataframe out of rows that already exist in the 2 dimensional dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Say I have the following 2 dimensional dataframe

```
+--------+-------------------+------------+
| Index, | Module/Line Item, | Is Module, |
+--------+-------------------+------------+
| 0,     | Module 1,         | True,      |
| 1,     | Line Item 1,      | False,     |
| 2,     | Line Item 2,      | False,     |
| 3,     | Module 2,         | True,      |
| 4,     | Line Item 1,      | False,     |
| 5,     | Line Item 2,      | False      |
+--------+-------------------+------------+
```

And I want it to turn into this:

```
+----------+-------------+
| Module   | Line Item   |
+----------+-------------+
| Module 1 | Line Item 1 |
|          | Line Item 2 |
| Module 2 | Line Item 1 |
|          | Line Item 2 |
+----------+-------------+
```

What would be the best way to accomplish that? Is there a built in way to pivot like that via pandas? I was messing with some regular python but it was very inefficient and I couldn't get it to work right.

Note there are not a set number of Line Items between Modules, and no patterns in the names. The "Is Module" column is the only indicator of whether the value is a module and should be pivoted. All Line items that appear beneath the module until the next module should belong to that module when pivoted.

This is not answered by [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe) because it never explains how to split a column into a hierarchy based on the values that are given in another column.

Comment: `pd.groupby`, `pd.pivot`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: This is not answered by How to pivot a dataframe because it never explains how to split a column into a hierarchy based on the values that are given in another column. It only explains how to use a single column as the index instead of another one. I'm not looking to pivot per-se but split a column into a new level based on a boolean value held in column 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't pivoting, it's that you have two columns in one column. There may be a more programmatic way to do this, but here's a go at getting it in the right shape and order, then you can group and pivot as necessary.

Create data:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'mod_lin':['m1','l1','l2','m2','l1','l2'],'is_mod':[True,False,False,True,False,False]})

    mod_lin is_mod
0   m1      True
1   l1      False
2   l2      False
3   m2      True
4   l1      False
5   l2      False
```

Make new column for modules, forward fill, remove modules from original column, drop True/False column, reorder columns

```
df['mods']=np.where(df['is_mod']==True, df['mod_lin'],np.NaN)

df['mods']=df['mods'].fillna(method='ffill')

df=df[df['is_mod']==False]

df.drop('is_mod', axis=1, inplace=True)

df=df[df.columns[::-1]]

    mods    mod_lin
1   m1      l1
2   m1      l2
4   m2      l1
5   m2      l2
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html

With dataframe, you can pivot table.

Comment: This isn't working for what I want. I want to split a column based on the boolean flag and use the True values as the new index and keep the values under those that are false to the right of those values.